# PyTorch throws runtime errors when finetuning LLM for summarization (Google Colab Pro+)

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, google-colaboratory

For context, I am attempting to test out Stanford's BioMedLM model by attempting to verify the summarization examples [seen in this article](https://hai.stanford.edu/news/stanford-crfm-introduces-pubmedgpt-27b) (scroll down to "Text Generation" to see the examples I'm referring to). I am following [the instructions detailed on the GitHub page](https://github.com/stanford-crfm/BioMedLM/tree/main/finetune) for running the summarization tasks. I'm using my Google Colab Pro+ subscription for this since I don't have access to a Nvidia Ampere GPU.

When I was attempting to test out this model, I decided to clone the GitHub repo for BioMedLM into my Colab notebook and follow the instructions from the GitHub page. According to that page, I need to run the following command (or at least, since I'm not too familiar with what all of these flags mean, my version of this command):

```
python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=8 --nnodes=1 --node_rank=0 finetune_for_summarization.py --output_dir {run_dir} --model_name_or_path stanford-crfm/BioMedLM --tokenizer_name stanford-crfm/pubmed_gpt_tokenizer --per_device_train_batch_size 1 --per_device_eval_batch_size 1 --save_strategy no --do_eval --train_data_file data/meqsum/train.source --eval_data_file data/meqsum/val.source --save_total_limit 2 --overwrite_output_dir --gradient_accumulation_steps 1 --learning_rate 1e-5 --warmup_ratio 0.5 --weight_decay 0.0 --seed 7 --evaluation_strategy steps --eval_steps 200 --bf16 --num_train_epochs 3 --logging_steps 100 --logging_first_step
```

Whenever I attempt running this code, I get the following error log (truncated to focus on the most relevant errors):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/BioMedLM/finetune/textgen/gpt2/finetune_for_summarization.py", line 151, in <module>
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/training_args.py", line 1468, in _setup_devices
        return func(*args, **kwargs)finetune()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/training_args.py", line 1468, in _setup_devices
  File "/content/BioMedLM/finetune/textgen/gpt2/finetune_for_summarization.py", line 105, in finetune
    model_args, data_args, training_args = parser.parse_args_into_dataclasses()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/hf_argparser.py", line 226, in parse_args_into_dataclasses
    torch.cuda.set_device(device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 350, in set_device
    obj = dtype(**inputs)
  File "<string>", line 104, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/training_args.py", line 1118, in __post_init__
    torch._C._cuda_setDevice(device)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

For some context, I am using these runtime settings:

- Hardware accelerator: GPU
- GPU class: Premium
- Runtime shape: High-RAM

I've tried looking for answers on Stack Overflow and other related websites (such as PyTorch), but I couldn't find solutions that were either up-to-date or even useful—let alone ones that match my specific use case. I would like to find a way of fixing this problem without modifying the source code, since that kind of defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do.

Please let me know if you need more information to figure out what's going on.

Comment: What is the output from `pip list` in the Python environment in which you are running the above code? Have you made sure to install the correct modules and their versions?

Comment: @KyleFHartzenberg Here's the output from `pip list` (cont. in next comments): `absl-py=1.4.0
aiohttp=3.8.4
aiosignal=1.3.1
alabaster=0.7.13
albumentations=1.2.1
altair=4.2.2
anyio=3.6.2
appdirs=1.4.4
argon2-cffi=21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0
arviz=0.15.1
astropy=5.2.2
astunparse=1.6.3
async-timeout=4.0.2
attrs=22.2.0
audioread=3.0.0
autograd=1.5
Babel=2.12.1
backcall=0.2.0
beautifulsoup4=4.11.2
bleach=6.0.0
blis=0.7.9
blosc2=2.0.0
bokeh=2.4.3
branca=0.6.0
CacheControl=0.12.11
cached-property=1.5.2
cachetools=5.3.0
catalogue=2.0.8
certifi=2022.12.7`

Comment: (cont.): `cffi=1.15.1
chardet=4.0.0
charset-normalizer=2.0.12
chex=0.1.7
click=8.1.3
cloudpickle=2.2.1
cmake=3.25.2
cmdstanpy=1.1.0
colorama=0.4.6
colorcet=3.0.1
colorlover=0.3.0
community=1.0.0b1
confection=0.0.4
cons=0.4.5
contextlib2=0.6.0.post1
contourpy=1.0.7
convertdate=2.4.0
cryptography=40.0.1
cufflinks=0.17.3
cupy-cuda11x=11.0.0
cvxopt=1.3.0
cvxpy=1.3.1
cycler=0.11.0
cymem=2.0.7
Cython=0.29.34
dask=2022.12.1
datascience=0.17.6
datasets=2.6.1
db-dtypes=1.1.1
dbus-python=1.2.16
debugpy=1.6.6
decorator=4.4.2
defusedxml=0.7.1
dill=0.3.5.1`

Comment: (cont.): `distributed=2022.12.1
dlib=19.24.1
dm-tree=0.1.8
docker-pycreds=0.4.0
docutils=0.16
dopamine-rl=4.0.6
earthengine-api=0.1.347
easydict=1.10
ecos=2.0.12
editdistance=0.6.2
en-core-web-sm=3.5.0
entrypoints=0.4
ephem=4.1.4
et-xmlfile=1.1.0
etils=1.1.1
etuples=0.3.8
exceptiongroup=1.1.1
fairscale=0.4.12
fastai=2.7.12
fastcore=1.5.29
fastdownload=0.0.7
fastjsonschema=2.16.3
fastprogress=1.0.3
fastrlock=0.8.1
filelock=3.10.7
firebase-admin=5.3.0
Flask=2.2.3
flatbuffers=23.3.3
flax=0.6.8
folium=0.14.0
fonttools=4.39.3
frozendict=2.3.6`

Comment: (cont.): `frozenlist=1.3.3
fsspec=2023.3.0
future=0.18.3
gast=0.4.0
GDAL=3.3.2
gdown=4.6.6
gensim=4.3.1
geographiclib=2.0
geopy=2.3.0
gin-config=0.5.0
gitdb=4.0.10
GitPython=3.1.31
glob2=0.7
google=2.0.3
google-api-core=2.11.0
google-api-python-client=2.70.0
google-auth=2.17.1
google-auth-httplib2=0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib=1.0.0
google-cloud-bigquery=3.4.2
google-cloud-bigquery-storage=2.19.1
google-cloud-core=2.3.2
google-cloud-datastore=2.11.1
google-cloud-firestore=2.7.3
google-cloud-language=2.6.1
google-cloud-storage=2.7.0
google-cloud-translate=3.8.4`

Comment: (cont.): `google-colab=1.0.0
google-crc32c=1.5.0
google-pasta=0.2.0
google-resumable-media=2.4.1
googleapis-common-protos=1.59.0
googledrivedownloader=0.4
graphviz=0.20.1
greenlet=2.0.2
grpcio=1.53.0
grpcio-status=1.48.2
gspread=3.4.2
gspread-dataframe=3.0.8
gym=0.25.2
gym-notices=0.0.8
h5netcdf=1.1.0
h5py=3.8.0
HeapDict=1.0.1
hijri-converter=2.2.4
holidays=0.22
holoviews=1.15.4
html5lib=1.1
htmlmin=0.1.12
httpimport=1.3.0
httplib2=0.21.0
huggingface-hub=0.10.1
humanize=4.6.0
hyperopt=0.2.7
idna=3.4
ImageHash=4.3.1
imageio=2.25.1
imageio-ffmpeg=0.4.8`

Comment: (cont.): `imagesize=1.4.1
imbalanced-learn=0.10.1
imgaug=0.4.0
importlib-metadata=6.1.0
importlib-resources=5.12.0
imutils=0.5.4
inflect=6.0.2
iniconfig=2.0.0
intel-openmp=2023.1.0
ipykernel=5.5.6
ipython=7.34.0
ipython-genutils=0.2.0
ipython-sql=0.4.1
ipywidgets=7.7.1
itsdangerous=2.1.2
jax=0.4.7
jaxlib=0.4.7+cuda11.cudnn86
jieba=0.42.1
Jinja2=3.1.2
joblib=1.1.1
jsonpickle=3.0.1
jsonschema=4.3.3
jupyter-client=6.1.12
jupyter-console=6.1.0
jupyter_core=5.3.0
jupyter-server=1.23.6
jupyterlab-pygments=0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets=3.0.7
kaggle=1.5.13
keras=2.12.0`

Comment: (cont.): `keras-vis=0.4.1
kiwisolver=1.4.4
korean-lunar-calendar=0.3.1
langcodes=3.3.0
lazy_loader=0.2
libclang=16.0.0
librosa=0.10.0.post2
lightgbm=3.3.5
lit=16.0.0
llvmlite=0.39.1
locket=1.0.0
logical-unification=0.4.5
LunarCalendar=0.0.9
lxml=4.9.2
Markdown=3.4.3
markdown-it-py=2.2.0
MarkupSafe=2.1.2
matplotlib=3.7.1
matplotlib-inline=0.1.6
matplotlib-venn=0.11.9
mdurl=0.1.2
miniKanren=1.0.3
missingno=0.5.2
mistune=0.8.4
mizani=0.8.1
mkl=2019.0
ml-dtypes=0.0.4
mlxtend=0.14.0
more-itertools=9.1.0
moviepy=1.0.3
mpmath=1.3.0
msgpack=1.0.5
multidict=6.0.4`

Comment: (cont.): `multimethod=1.9.1
multipledispatch=0.6.0
multiprocess=0.70.13
multitasking=0.0.11
murmurhash=1.0.9
music21=8.1.0
natsort=8.3.1
nbclient=0.7.3
nbconvert=6.5.4
nbformat=5.8.0
nest-asyncio=1.5.6
networkx=3.0
nibabel=3.0.2
nltk=3.8.1
notebook=6.4.8
numba=0.56.4
numexpr=2.8.4
numpy=1.22.4
oauth2client=4.1.3
oauthlib=3.2.2
opencv-contrib-python=4.7.0.72
opencv-python=4.7.0.72
opencv-python-headless=4.7.0.72
openpyxl=3.0.10
opt-einsum=3.3.0
optax=0.1.4
orbax=0.1.7
osqp=0.6.2.post0
packaging=23.0
palettable=3.3.0
pandas=1.4.4
pandas-datareader=0.10.0`

Comment: (cont.): `pandas-gbq=0.17.9
pandas-profiling=3.2.0
pandocfilters=1.5.0
panel=0.14.4
param=1.13.0
parso=0.8.3
partd=1.3.0
pathlib=1.0.1
pathtools=0.1.2
pathy=0.10.1
patsy=0.5.3
pep517=0.13.0
pexpect=4.8.0
phik=0.12.3
pickleshare=0.7.5
Pillow=8.4.0
pip=22.0.4
pip-tools=6.6.2
platformdirs=3.2.0
plotly=5.13.1
plotnine=0.10.1
pluggy=1.0.0
pooch=1.6.0
portalocker=2.7.0
portpicker=1.3.9
prefetch-generator=1.0.3
preshed=3.0.8
prettytable=0.7.2
proglog=0.1.10
progressbar2=4.2.0
prometheus-client=0.16.0
promise=2.3
prompt-toolkit=3.0.38
prophet=1.1.2`

Comment: (cont.): `proto-plus=1.22.2
protobuf=3.20.3
psutil=5.9.4
psycopg2=2.9.6
ptyprocess=0.7.0
py-cpuinfo=9.0.0
py4j=0.10.9.7
pyarrow=9.0.0
pyasn1=0.4.8
pyasn1-modules=0.2.8
pycocotools=2.0.6
pycparser=2.21
pyct=0.5.0
pydantic=1.10.7
pydata-google-auth=1.7.0
pydot=1.4.2
pydot-ng=2.0.0
pydotplus=2.0.2
PyDrive=1.3.1
pyerfa=2.0.0.3
pygame=2.3.0
Pygments=2.14.0
PyGObject=3.36.0
pymc=5.1.2
PyMeeus=0.5.12
pymystem3=0.2.0
PyOpenGL=3.1.6
pyparsing=3.0.9
pyrsistent=0.19.3
PySocks=1.7.1
pytensor=2.10.1
pytest=7.2.2
python-apt=0.0.0
python-dateutil=2.8.2
python-louvain=0.16`

Comment: (cont.): `python-slugify=8.0.1
python-utils=3.5.2
pytz=2022.7.1
pytz-deprecation-shim=0.1.0.post0
pyviz-comms=2.2.1
PyWavelets=1.4.1
PyYAML=6.0
pyzmq=23.2.1
qdldl=0.1.5.post3
qudida=0.0.4
regex=2022.10.31
requests=2.27.1
requests-oauthlib=1.3.1
requests-unixsocket=0.2.0
responses=0.18.0
rich=13.3.3
rouge-score=0.0.4
rpy2=3.5.5
rsa=4.9
sacrebleu=2.0.0
scikit-image=0.19.3
scikit-learn=1.2.2
scipy=1.10.1
scs=3.2.2
seaborn=0.12.2
Send2Trash=1.8.0
sentry-sdk=1.19.1
setproctitle=1.3.2
setuptools=67.6.1
shapely=2.0.1
shortuuid=1.0.11
six=1.16.0
sklearn-pandas=2.2.0`

Comment: (cont.): `smart-open=6.3.0
smmap=5.0.0
sniffio=1.3.0
snowballstemmer=2.2.0
sortedcontainers=2.4.0
soundfile=0.12.1
soupsieve=2.4
soxr=0.3.4
spacy=3.5.1
spacy-legacy=3.0.12
spacy-loggers=1.0.4
Sphinx=3.5.4
sphinxcontrib-applehelp=1.0.4
sphinxcontrib-devhelp=1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp=2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-jsmath=1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp=1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml=1.1.5
SQLAlchemy=1.4.47
sqlparse=0.4.3
srsly=2.4.6
statsmodels=0.13.5
sympy=1.11.1
tables=3.8.0
tabulate=0.8.10
tangled-up-in-unicode=0.2.0
tblib=1.7.0
tenacity=8.2.2
tensorboard=2.12.1`

Comment: (cont.): `tensorboard-data-server=0.7.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.8.1
tensorflow=2.12.0
tensorflow-datasets=4.8.3
tensorflow-estimator=2.12.0
tensorflow-gcs-config=2.12.0
tensorflow-hub=0.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem=0.32.0
tensorflow-metadata=1.13.0
tensorflow-probability=0.19.0
tensorstore=0.1.35
termcolor=2.2.0
terminado=0.17.1
text-unidecode=1.3
textblob=0.17.1
tf-slim=1.1.0
thinc=8.1.9
threadpoolctl=3.1.0
tifffile=2023.3.21
tinycss2=1.2.1
tokenizers=0.13.3
toml=0.10.2
tomli=2.0.1
toolz=0.12.0
torch=2.0.0+cu118
torchaudio=2.0.1+cu118
torchdata=0.6.0`

Comment: (cont.): `torchsummary=1.5.1
torchtext=0.15.1
torchvision=0.15.1+cu118
tornado=6.2
tqdm=4.65.0
traitlets=5.7.1
transformers=4.24.0
triton=2.0.0
tweepy=4.13.0
typer=0.7.0
typing_extensions=4.5.0
tzdata=2023.3
tzlocal=4.3
uritemplate=4.1.1
urllib3=1.26.15
vega-datasets=0.9.0
visions=0.7.4
wandb=0.13.5
wasabi=1.1.1
wcwidth=0.2.6
webcolors=1.13
webencodings=0.5.1
websocket-client=1.5.1
Werkzeug=2.2.3
wheel=0.40.0
widgetsnbextension=3.6.4
wordcloud=1.8.2.2
wrapt=1.14.1
xarray=2022.12.0
xarray-einstats=0.5.1
xgboost=1.7.5
xlrd=2.0.1
xxhash=3.2.0
yarl=1.8.2`

Comment: (cont. [last one, sorry for the spam]): `yellowbrick=1.5
yfinance=0.2.14
zict=2.2.0
zipp=3.15.0`

Comment: @KyleFHartzenberg To answer your other question, I believe that I have the correct PyTorch and CUDA related packages installed in my environment (although these packages came preinstalled with Google Colab). I also have all of the required packages from the BioMedLM GitHub repo. Please correct me if I am wrong about this.

Comment: The [requirements/dependencies](https://github.com/stanford-crfm/BioMedLM/tree/main/finetune#dependencies) on the GitHub page you link list `python=3.8.12`, and `pytorch=1.12.1` but you are running Python 3.9 and `torch==2.0.0`.  You also need to make sure `cudatoolkit==11.3` is available and that your Nvidia drivers support it. First run `nvidia-smi` in the command prompt and check the output, then run `nvcc --version` to check if the CUDA compiler matches the version supplied by `nvidia-smi` output.

Comment: @KyleFHartzenberg I ran `nvidia-smi` and `nvcc --version`, and it seems that the drivers don't match. The former returned CUDA 12.0 and the latter returned CUDA 11.8.

Comment: That is okay, the version from `nvidia-smi` is the most recent version of the CUDA compiler that the Nvidia drivers will support. So as long as the CUDA compiler (`nvcc --version <= 12.0`), you are good on that front. What I think is more likely the issue is the `torch` version. The requirements for BioMedLM list `1.12.1`with CUDA `11.3`, whereas you are using `2.0.0` with CUDA `11.8`. First try installing an [older version](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#v1121) (version 1.12.1 uses CUDA 11.6, if that fails, then also downgrade your CUDA version from 11.8 to 11.6 to match)